# Flutter Nested JSON Parsing

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have a nested JSON api here:

```
[
  {
    "Employee": {
      "Name": "Michael Jackson",
      "Identification": "881228145031",
      "Company": "Test Corporate",
      "DateOfBirth": "1988-12-28",
      "Entitlements": {
        "GP": {
          "Entitlement": "10000",
          "Utilisation": "500",
          "Balance": "9500"
        },
        "OPS": {
          "Entitlement": "10000",
          "Utilisation": "500",
          "Balance": "9500"
        },
        "IP": {
          "Entitlement": "50000",
          "Utilisation": "17000",
          "Balance": "33000"
        },
        "Dental": {
          "Entitlement": "0.00",
          "Utilisation": "0.00",
          "Balance": "0.00"
        },
        "Optical": {
          "Entitlement": "500",
          "Utilisation": "0.00",
          "Balance": "500"
        },
        "EHS": {
          "Entitlement": "1000",
          "Utilisation": "250",
          "Balance": "750"
        }
      }
    },
    "Dependents": [
      {
        "Name": "Kim",
        "Relationship": "Parent",
        "Entitlements": {
          "GP": {
            "Entitlement": "10000",
            "Utilisation": "500",
            "Balance": "9500"
          },
          "OPS": {
            "Entitlement": "10000",
            "Utilisation": "500",
            "Balance": "9500"
          },
          "IP": {
            "Entitlement": "50000",
            "Utilisation": "17000",
            "Balance": "33000"
          },
          "Dental": {
            "Entitlement": "800",
            "Utilisation": "200",
            "Balance": "600"
          },
          "Optical": {
            "Entitlement": "500",
            "Utilisation": "0.00",
            "Balance": "500"
          },
          "EHS": {
            "Entitlement": "1000",
            "Utilisation": "250",
            "Balance": "750"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Tim",
        "Relationship": "Spouse",
        "Entitlements": {
          "GP": {
            "Entitlement": "10000",
            "Utilisation": "500",
            "Balance": "9500"
          },
          "OPS": {
            "Entitlement": "10000",
            "Utilisation": "500",
            "Balance": "9500"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, the JSON file has the same nest in both **Employee** and **Dependents** called **Entitlements** and it has a few Maps inside of it.

The basic Model class for both **Employee** and **Dependents** are as follows:

**crm_single_user_model.dart (Model for Employee)**

```
class SingleUser{

  final String name, identification, company, dob;

  SingleUser({this.name, this.identification, this.company, this.dob});

  factory SingleUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> ujson){

    return SingleUser(
      name: ujson["Name"].toString(),
      identification: ujson["Identification"].toString(),
      company: ujson["Company"].toString(),
      dob: ujson["DateOfBirth"].toString()
    );
  }
}
```

**crm_dependent_list_model.dart(Model for Dependents)**

```
class DependantModel{

  String name;
  String relationship;

  DependantModel({this.name, this.relationship});

  factory DependantModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> depjson){

    return DependantModel(
      name: depjson["Name"].toString(),
      relationship: depjson["Relationship"].toString()
    );
  }
}
```

My question is
**How do i make a model class for the Entitlements?**

I can't seem to come up with a solution to creating a model class with lots of maps inside of a map.

Your help is much appreciated in this matter.

Comment: just save it into a map

Comment: You can use a map and iterate map values to parse an array. If you want an example code, please let me know. I can explain how to convert a JSON response into a POJO equivalent of Java

Comment: Yes Jaswant, I could use an example code if thats not too much of a hassle.

Comment: @JaswantSingh sorry forgot to tag your name.

Comment: You may want to check json_resolve https://dev.to/onmyway133/how-to-resolve-deep-json-object-in-dart-5c5l

Answer (score 1):

try to  see that example

https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final List<Image> images;

  Product({this.id, this.name, this.images});
}

class Image {
  final int imageId;
  final String imageName;

  Image({this.imageId, this.imageName});
}
```