# I got this error while retrieving data from the api?

Tags: json, api, flutter

[image: This is the JSON data, i want to retrive]

what is the error in this code? In console, I got error like this

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of
>   type 'Iterable

```
class _MytimeoffState extends State<Mytimeoff> {

  List<Map> list = [];

  void getList() async {
    var data = await http
        .get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darshanaAlex/db2/time_off');
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map js in jsonData) {
        list.add(js);
      }
    });
    print(jsonData);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getList();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a `Map`
and it contains `List` at leavetypes !

But you are trying to access direct map into list

```
class _MytimeoffState extends State<Mytimeoff> {

  List<Map> list = [];
  Map leaveRoot ={};

  void getList() async {
    var data = await http
        .get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darshanaAlex/db2/time_off');
    leaveRoot = Map.from(json.decode(data.body));

    setState(() {
      for (Map js in leaveRoot['leavetype']) {
        list.add(js);
      }
    });
    print(jsonData);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getList();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
}
}
```

Comment: Yor are a genius man, Thank a lot, love you!!!, Now I'm working as an intern in one company, Any difficult task comes I never scared because of you. Thank you!!!!